# Does python has methods similar to __setattr__ but for python class?

Tags: python

Currently **__setattr__** only works for instance. Is there any similar method for class? I am asking this question because I want to collect the list of defined attribute in order when user define it in class as below:

```
class CfgObj(object):
    _fields = []
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self._fields.append([name, value])
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

class ACfg(CfgObj):
    setting1 = Field(str, default='set1', desc='setting1 ...')
    setting2 = Field(int, default=5, desc='setting2...')
```

I know the above code will not work as expected because the **__setattr__** only called by instance as below:

```
acfg = ACfg()
acfg.c = 1
acfg._fields == [['c', 1]]
```

So, is there any equivalent **__setattr__** for python class? The main purpose is to collect the define attribute in order when user define it in class.

Comment: what are you trying to do? can you give an example?

Comment: Take a look at the way Django does it with its forms. It's good stuff. Put a counter in `Field` so each instance gets an ID, and use a metaclass to sort the fields by that counter into `_fields`.

Comment: I want to create a Configuration Class map to an xml config file and the same time using this Class to generate a GUI for user to change the value. I want the GUI to generate the setting in the order they defined, else using python dict will not preserve the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do to solve your *problem* - but not your *question* - is to <del>set the timestamp of the field creation</del> create a counter of `Field` objects and set the current value of the counter to the created one:

```
class Field(object):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, value, default=None, desc=None):
        self.value = value
        self.default = default
        self.desc = desc
        # Here comes the magic
        self.nth = Field.count
        Field.count += 1
        # self.created_at = time.time()
```

Then I would create a method for returning all fields ordered by its counter value:

```
class CfgObj(object):
    def params(self):
        ns = dir(self)
        fs = [getattr(self, field) 
                    for field in ns 
                    if isinstance(getattr(self, field), Field)]
        # fs = sorted(fs, key=lambda f: f.created_at)
        fs = sorted(fs, key=lambda f: f.nth)
        return fs
```

Its usage is intuitive:

```
class ACfg(CfgObj):
    setting1 = Field(str, default='set1', desc='setting1 ...')
    setting2 = Field(int, default=5, desc='setting2...')

print ACfg().params()
```

Clearly the fields are ordered by time of *object* creation, not *field* creation, but it can be enough for you. Is it?

Comment: Using time in this case isn't wise (can you guarantee they will be distinct?) or necessary. I'd do it the way Django does it - have a counter in the `Field` class which is incremented for each instance and then just compare that. And then use a metaclass to have it automatically put into your class (so you could just do `ACfg().fields` and it would be a list of them in the correct order).

Comment: Good point, @Chris. I updated my answer (but did not used metaclasses because my prejudices say they are evil :D )

Comment: Thanks, a lot!! Its behave exactly what I wanted. Although the Field counter will be big because I will have lots of class creating the same Field but I don't see a big issue here. I never think of solving this issue with this tricks....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but [that's not how you want to do it](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta/index.html).

```
class MC(type):
  def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
    print dct
    super(MC, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class C(object):
  __metaclass__ = MC
  foo = 42
```

Answer (score 3):

If you define `__setattr__()`  on the metaclass of a class, it will be called when setting attributes on the class, but only after creating the class:

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...     def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
...         print "%s=%r" % (name, value)
... 
>>> class A(object):
...     __metaclass__ = Meta
... 
>>> A.a = 1
a=1
```

But it won't work at the time of class definition, so it's probably not what you want.

Getting the class attributes in the metaclass `__init__()` works, but you loose the order of definition (and multiple definitions as well).

Comment: Its not what I wanted, but its good to know meta class have this capability.