# Defining __getattr__ and __setattr__ for Python class variables

Tags: python, class, setter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does python has methods similar to __setattr__ but for python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808012/does-python-has-methods-similar-to-setattr-but-for-python-class)

I'm trying to create my own forms framework, where a form can be defined like this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.Input(type='text',validators=[validators.Required(),validators.len(3,10)])
    pass‹ord = forms.Input(type='password', validators=[validators.Required(),validators.len(min=8)])
```

These Input instances also have a property `name`, but it would look silly if this had to be passed as a parameter in the constructor, because you've already named it with the variable name. So I did a very very simple test in the repl:

```
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def __setattr__(cls, key, value):
        cls.__dict__[key] = value
        cls.__dict__[key].name = key

class PropClass:
    pass

class SubClass(Base):
    x = PropClass()

SubClass().x.name
```

I hoped this would return "x", but it didn't.

For now, I have put some code in the Form constructor that iterates over its **dict**, checks for Field instances, and sets their name, which works just as well for me, but I'm still curios wether it is possible to define setters for class variables.

Comment: You could do this with metaclasses, but what is the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: @phant0m that's probably a dupe indeed, but it didn't come up when I searched, or in my suggested questions. I'll probably delete this. The problem Im' trying to solve, is giving an instance the name of the variable it was assigned to. If it were an instance variable, it'd be trivial to do with `__setitem__(self,k,v)`, in that case I could just pass k to v. (passing the name of the input to the input instance.)

Comment: Took a look at the other wwuestion. The accepted answer is the sollution I came up with. Also see se metaclassing answers in there. I'll have to take a look into that.

Comment: Don't delete the question. When someone else searches for the same thing you did, this question here might show up and they get redirected to the answer.

Comment: I'll flag it for dupe then?